# How to get a INT or STR from VAR with function return?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the user ID and I need this in INT format, but I only get with function return. How to convert from function to INT? I'm using Django 2.1.7 and python 3.7.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.http import HttpRequest
request=HttpRequest
username='myuser'
password='mypass'
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

def user_id(request):
    UID = request.user
    return(UID)

UID=user_id
print(type(UID))
<class 'function'>
print(UID)
<function user_id at 0x106cd9158>
print(user.id)
19 


views.py:
def get_userid(request):
    if User.is_authenticated:
        UID = request.user.id 
        return (UID)
    if User.is_anonymous:
        UID = 14
        return (UID)
def opsearch(request):
    item = request.POST['item']
    dic = MLRun(item)
    return render(request, 'main/layout/results.html', {'dictionary': dic})
```

my code which call template:

```
def to_DB(item, dic):
    UID = get_userid
    date_started = (timezone.now())
    item_searched = item

    Q = OPQuery(date_started=date_started, 
        item_searched=item_searched, id_user=UID)
    Q.save()
    QID = Q.id
    QUID = OPQuery.objects.get(id=QID)
```

The error:

```
TypeError at /main/search/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/search/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'
Exception Location: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 1807
Python Executable:  /Users/Documents/PycharmProjects/OP/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.2
```

Comment: You need to call the function.

Comment: But you can't have a request outside of a view, anyway. None of this code makes any sense.

Comment: @Sayse,  Please, how I call the function?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I did use this code in Django Shell just to simulate what I need. If you have any suggestion I appreciate to know it. Thank you.

Comment: But like I said, it makes no sense to talk about a request and a user when you're in the shell. Requests are made when a browser loads a page via a URL, and request.user is the user that is logged in to the site in that browser. What could it mean to talk about those things in the shell?

Comment: I know that, but  I'm simulate the some problem that I have  when I try on the browser. You got it?

Comment: No. Show your actual view code and the error you get in the browser.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I put up (in the description). Thank you!

Comment: Where is `to_DB` called from? Which is the actual view? What is MLRun?

Comment: MLRun is a function (def) in my test.py. That search item price in some URL and return items to DIC this DIC I insert into DB (MySQL) with  to to_DB function.

Comment: MLRun is a function (def) in my test.py. That search item price in some URL and return items to DICT this DICT I insert into DB (MySQL) with  to to_DB function. The way is : index.html(template) call opsearch in views with item var -> opsearch pass item var in MLRun function --> MLRun call MLSea function --> MLSea make requests into some APIs and returns the DICT Sorted to MLRUn --> MLRun call the to_DB to insert on my DB. Its works fine when I don't use the User ID. I write into DB ok! But, I cant write to DB because when I run request.user.id I received function return.

Comment: ... and I need to receive a INT return with the user ID.

Comment: I don't understand why all of my querys in Django returns only functions, not a String or integer.

Comment: from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.http import HttpRequest
request=HttpRequest
username='user@try'
password='teste'
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
def user_id(request):
    if User.is_authenticated:
        UID = request.POST.get('user.id')
        print(UID)
        return(UID)
    if User.is_anonymous:
        UID = 14
        return (UID)
UID=user_id
print(UID)
<function user_id at 0x10e0dc158>

Comment: @DanielRoseman If you runs the same command: request.user.id in your Django Shell, What is the returns that you have? Can you show me your return, please? 
I'm intrigued. Thanks

Comment: FFS. *You cannot run that in the shell*. The request object has no meaning outside of a view.

Comment: You get a function because *you did not actually **call** the user_id function*.

Answer (score 0):

This code is really full of problems. Here are some of them.

In `to_DB`:

- You don't actually *call* the `get_userid` function, you just reference it. This is the cause of your immediate error. In Python you always need to use `()` to call a function.
- You don't pass the `request` argument to that function.
- You don't return anything from that function.
- Since you already created the OPQuery object, why do you then immediately query it back from the db? You already have it.
- You don't use the `dic` parameter anywehere.

In `get_userid`:

- `is_authenticated` needs to be called on the current user instance, not the user class. It should be `request.user.is_authenticated`.
- Similarly for `is_anonymous`.
- You don't need parentheses around return values.
- This whole function is pointless, in any case.

Being as constructive as possible, you are struggling with basic Python concepts here. You really need to go back and do an introductory Python tutorial and then the Django tutorial.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help and time. I'm beginner in Python and Django it's true. Your tricks help me a lot. I appreciate that!